# Is it possible to reduce graphic processor power consumption?

Tags: power-management

Is it possible to reduce graphic processor power consumption?

My notebook powered with nVIDIA GT230M graphic processor and its power consumption is about 45W, it eats my battery!

> Other Specs:
>
> 15.6" monitor
> 4GB of RAM
> 720QM CPU

Comment: And this is why I went with integrated graphics. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modern graphics drivers include a internal automatic power management. I don't know if this option is configurable in your graphic card.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try looking for both driver, BIOS and graphics BIOS updates in the hopes that they have added this functionality, but, it is doubtful.

Typically, the more powerful the graphics card in the laptop, the higher the capacity of the battery that comes with it for this very reason.

Unless you have Optimus or some other sort of Hybrid technology, there isn't anything you can do :( - Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce your graphic processor's power consumption, you can try to reduce its clock speed (underclocking), memory speed, and if possible, voltage.  For this, you will need an overclocking tool that supports your GPU.

I'm not sure if [Nvidia System Tools](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvidia_system_tools_6.06.html) supports this, but you might also want to try other third-party tools.  Some of these tools that come to mind are [RivaTuner](http://www.guru3d.com/index.php?page=rivatuner), [PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm), or [ATITool](http://www.techpowerup.com/atitool/) (which despite the name, can handle Nvidia GPUs).